# Move back x members in same hierarchy

Tags: ssas, mdx

Is there a function which moves back a set number of members in a specified hierarchy's level?

It would be something like the following if I want to move back two members:

```
SOMEFUNCTION([someMember], [specifiedLevel],-2)
```

So an example would be:

```
WITH MEMBER [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[2MthPrev] AS
    SOMEFUNCTION(
    CLOSINGPERIOD([Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month]),
    [Date].[Date - Calendar Month].[Calendar Month],
    -2
    )
```

Comment: Please clarify the relation between [specifiedLevel] and [someMember].

Comment: @MarcPolizzi I suppose [someMember] would be part of [specifiedLevel]....although I think maybe Lag as specified by kzhen is possibly what I'm after - are there better ways? This other question of mine is linked in with the above as I thought `ANCESTOR` might help - [SO QUESTION](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17489503/using-the-ancestor-function-on-a-date-dimension)

Comment: I would have proposed Lag as well...

Comment: @MarcPolizzi - thanks Marc - Lag it is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few different functions that you could try out:

**Lag:** Returns the member that is a specified number of positions before a specified member at the member's level.

Example: this will return December 2001

```
SELECT [Date].[Fiscal].[Month].[February 2002].Lag(2) ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144866.aspx for more details

**ParallelPeriod**: Returns a member from a prior period in the same relative position as a specified member.

Example:

```
SELECT ParallelPeriod ([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Quarter], 3, 
       [Date].[Calendar].[Month].[October 2003]) ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145500.aspx for more details

(Examples are taken from the technet site)